# react hook form: how can i validate a group of radio buttons or checkboxes to ensure at least one is selected

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a group of checkboxes and a group if radios and I want to validate with react hook form to ensure that an error message is generated if none have been selected on submit.

I have tried experimenting with the form builder on their website but I cant work out how to validate a group of items as a single unit of validation.

```
<div>
  <span>Option A <input type="checkbox" value="A" /></span>
  <span>Option B <input type="checkbox" value="B" /></span>
  <span>Option C <input type="checkbox" value="C" /></span>
</div>
<...output a validation error if one or more checkboxes hasnt been checked within the group>
```

```
<div>
  <span>Option A <input type="radio" value="A" /></span>
  <span>Option B <input type="radio" value="B" /></span>
  <span>Option C <input type="radio" value="C" /></span>
</div>
<...output a validation error if one or more radios hasnt been checked within the group>
```

Is this possible and is there a correct way to do it?

Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 6):

You added the `react-hook-form` tag to your question but there is nothing in your code related to it. If indeed you're using React Hook Form a way to accomplish what you want is using [schema validation](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#SchemaValidation) through `yup`:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  checkbox: yup.array().min(1),
  radio: yup.string().required(),
});

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <span>
        Checkbox 1
        <input type="checkbox" {...register('checkbox')} value="A" />
      </span>
      <span>
        Checkbox 1
        <input type="checkbox" {...register('checkbox')} value="B" />
      </span>
      <span>
        Checkbox 3
        <input type="checkbox" {...register('checkbox')} value="C" />
      </span>
      <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>
        {errors.checkbox && 'At least one checkobox must be selected'}
      </p>
      <span>
        <label>Radio 1</label>
        <input type="radio" {...register('radio')} value="A" />
      </span>
      <span>
        <label>Radio 2</label>
        <input type="radio" {...register('radio')} value="B" />
      </span>
      <span>
        <label>Radio 3</label>
        <input type="radio" {...register('radio')} value="C" />
      </span>
      <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.radio && 'Radio is required'}</p>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

See a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l3io1m).

Note that as radio button options are exclusive (only one can be selected) you're just sayng that the field is required.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this guide](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-radio-buttons-in-reactjs) and [the documentation for radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

In short, giving the same `name` attribute to your radio buttons ensures that only one of them can be selected at a time. Adding an `onChange` function linked to a `useState` within your component allows you to track the selected value and react if none has been selected.

The resulting code should be something like this:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(null);

  const onValueChange = e => {
    setMyValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div onChange={onValueChange}>
        <span>
          Option A <input type="checkbox" value="A" name="myValue" />
        </span>
        <span>
          Option B <input type="checkbox" value="B" name="myValue" />
        </span>
        <span>
          Option C <input type="checkbox" value="C" name="myValue" />
        </span>
      </div>
      {!myValue && <span>Please select a value</span>}
    </div>
  );
};
```